# How to calculate the weight between neurons in ANN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am currently learning Supervised ANN training using Backpropogation and I am stuck in this exercise. I calculated the δA using the equation at the bottom of the screenshot, however, I am unable to calculate δB because the weight of BD is not given. How do I find the weight of BD?

[image: Backpropogation Question]

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Please edit the question to cite your sources and provide proper attribution to the source of the material in that image -- see https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Thank you!

Comment: Please define all notation, including $net_A$ and $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the information provided does not appear to be enough to answer your question, though I confess I am not familiar with what a "unipolar continuous threshold function" is, and it is not clear to me what $f(\text{net}_A$) represents nor what the loss function for this task is.  You might need to talk to your instructor or wherever you got that image from.  You might ask them what a "-" over an edge means.